Add a rectangle to a PDF using R
Is there a way of how I can add a rectangle as an annotation to a PDF in R.
In Python I could use the PyMuPDF/fitz package to achieve this (see also doc).
I have looked at the pdftools package, but it can only extract text and not write.
If possible I do not want to involve reticulate to invoke python, but I would be ok with standard Linux tools that I can call using system.
Mockup Code (not working!)
file <- "https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftools/pdftools.pdf"

pdf <- read_pdf(file)
rectangle <- rect(0, 100, 200, 500, fill = "red", opacity = 0.5, color = "red")
pdf <- add_annotation(pdf, rectangle)
save_pdf(pdf, "outfile.pdf")


Maybe load the pdf , plot a rectangle in a plot window, and designate the pdf image as a "background" to the plot?

Ideally, I do not want to convert the PDF to an image but keep the text properties

Well, the fundamental problem is that PDF is a container, not a text or image format.   Depending on how your source PDF was created, different things are possible or impossible.
